# How to create a regular expression in node js?

Tags: node.js, regex, string

sample data is like

```
@ID_111_I1_0.000_I2_0.00_I3_-0.999*
@ID_232_TS_09.0*
```

I created one regular expression like :

```
const reg = new RegExp(/^@ID_[A-Z0-9._-]*\*/i);
```

but this will show valid true for strings like   `@ID_111_I1_0.000_I2*`

here `I2`  key is there, but its value is not showing
string start with this `@ID` .   then split with `_`  key value pair and string end with `*`
Please help me with a solution !!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do with this regular expression. What is your desired output?

Comment: What is the problem in matching `@ID_111_I1_0.000_I2*` ?

Comment: is this of help: https://regex101.com/r/n3CJmI/1 ?

Comment: @anubhava   when matching with that string its validation comes as true . but I2 have no value .. I1 value is 0.000 like wise I2 also have value . but in this string its missing .so if this string not matching with this regular expression i want to ignore this string .

Comment: @AkhilaV: So it should match `@ID_111_I1_0.000` part or it should not match at all?

Comment: You may use `/^@ID_[A-Z0-9.-]+(?:_[A-Z0-9]+_[A-Z0-9.-]+)*\*$/`

Comment: Don't do `new RegExp(/regexp/)` because `new RegExp("regexp")` is the same as `/regexp/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the following works for you:

```
^@ID_\d+(?:_[A-Z\d]+_-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+\*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uMB5V2/1)

- `^` -Start string anchor.
- `@ID_` - Match literally what is mentioned.
- `\d+` - 1+ numbers 0-9 to get the ID#.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group:

  - `_[A-Z\d]+` - An underscore followed by 1+ alphanumeric characters.
  - `_-?\d+` - An underscore, optional hyphen and 1+ digits.
  - `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group:

    - `\.\d+` - A literal dot and 1+ numbers.
    - `)?` - Close 2nd non-capture group and make it optional.
  - `)+` - Close 1st non-capture group and match it 1+ times.
- `\*` - Literal asterisk.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Note that I made it optional to have decimals in the key-value pairs. You could make it obligatory if need be:

```
^@ID_\d+(?:_[A-Z\d]+_-?\d+\.\d+)+\*$
```

Comment: Nicely explained